# how to reverse a sentence with a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, reverse

For an assignment, I need to use a `while` loop to reverse a list, and I just can't do it.

This is the sample code I have to help me get started:

```
sentence = raw_int ("   ")
length = len(sentence) # determines the length of the sentence (how many characters there are)
index = length - 1 #subtracts one from the length because we will be using indexes which start at zero rather than 1 like len

while... #while the index is greater than or equal to zero continue the loop
letter = sentence[index] #take the number from the index in the sentence and assigns it to the variable letter
```

I need to use this in my solution.

Comment: I don't know Python, but it's clear that your While loop is going to be looking at the variable "index" (so, "while index > 0").  Inside the while loop, you'll probably subtract 1 from index, and the variable "letter" will be the character you print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = raw_input("   ")
length = len(sentence)
index = length - 1
reversed_sentence = ''

while index >= 0:
    #letter is the last letter of the original sentence
    letter = sentence[index] 
    #make the first letter of the new sentence the last letter of the old sentence
    reversed_sentence += letter 
    #update the index so it now points to the second to last letter of the original sentence
    index = index - 1 

print reversed_sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an assignment, I'm not going to give you the full code. But I will give you two 'hints'.
1) a sentenced is reversed if every character is 'flipped'. For example, 'I ran fast'-to flip this sentence first swap 'I' and 'f', then space and 's' and so on.
2) you can use syntax like:

```
Sentence[i], sentence[len(sentence)-i] = sentence[len(sentence)-i], Sentence[i]
```

This should definitely be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
new_sentence = list()
sentence = list(raw_input("   "))

while sentence:
    new_sentence.append(sentence.pop(-1))
else:
    sentence = ''.join(new_sentence)
```